# How to configure wso2 metadata in Spring Security Sample

Tags: spring-security, wso2, saml

I am new in security and I downloaded spring security sample from github which running fine with ssocircle. Now I want to configure it with wso2. I read some articles of that, there they mention we have to manually write metadata. Please advice me how I can write metadata and instead of this metadata url which is defined in spring security sample

> http://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml which url I have to give.
>   Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this change the spring SAML sample project by adding a metadata xml file for IS as WSO2 doesn't auto generate you need to add a manually created metadata to your idp.xml,it will be somthing like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
                 entityID="localhost"
                 validUntil="2023-09-23T06:57:15.396Z">
  <md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" >
<md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
    <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate>MIICNTCCAZ6gAwIBAgIES343gjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UE
                CAwCQ0ExFjAUBgNVBAcMDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxDTALBgNVBAoMBFdTTzIxEjAQBgNVBAMMCWxv
                Y2FsaG9zdDAeFw0xMDAyMTkwNzAyMjZaFw0zNTAyMTMwNzAyMjZaMFUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQsw
                CQYDVQQIDAJDQTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzENMAsGA1UECgwEV1NPMjESMBAGA1UE
                AwwJbG9jYWxob3N0MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUp/oV1vWc8/TkQSiAvTou
                sMzOM4asB2iltr2QKozni5aVFu818MpOLZIr8LMnTzWllJvvaA5RAAdpbECb+48FjbBe0hseUdN5
                HpwvnH/DW8ZccGvk53I6Orq7hLCv1ZHtuOCokghz/ATrhyPq+QktMfXnRS4HrKGJTzxaCcU7OQID
                AQABoxIwEDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBPAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAW5wPR7cr1LAdq+IrR44i
                QlRG5ITCZXY9hI0PygLP2rHANh+PYfTmxbuOnykNGyhM6FjFLbW2uZHQTY1jMrPprjOrmyK5sjJR
                O4d1DeGHT/YnIjs9JogRKv4XHECwLtIVdAbIdWHEtVZJyMSktcyysFcvuhPQK8Qc/E/Wq8uHSCo=</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </md:KeyDescriptor>
    <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"   Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"    ResponseLocation="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
    <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"/>
   <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</NameIDFormat>
   <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</NameIDFormat>
   <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</NameIDFormat>
   <NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</NameIDFormat>
  </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

and add the entry for the IS metadata to the securityContext.xml.

---

Update :

in security-context.xml you need to change the metadata bean

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                            <constructor-arg value="/metadata/idp.xml"/>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>         
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
```

I hope this helped. -Paul

Comment: thats a very useful information but i need to know the path of the metadata which i have to give, as it is something which i am manually creating how the certificate is going to match

Comment: i have updated the answer krishan, you can check it now